# Python pandas dataframe transaction

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transactions, sqlalchemy

Please suggest a way to execute SQL statement and pandas dataframe .to_sql() in one transaction

I have the dataframe and want to delete some rows on the database side before insertion

So basically I need to delete and then insert in one transaction using .to_sql of dataframe

I use sqlalchemy engine with pandas.df.to_sql()

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation I realized that it is possible to do only with sqllite3, because to_sql supports both sqlalchemy engine and plain connection object as conn parameter, but as a connection it is supported only for sqllite3 database

In other words you have no influence on connection which will be created by to_sql function of dataframe